# Flutter remove item from collection with animation

Tags: flutter, animation, gridview

I have collection with `GridView` and now I want remove item/items from this collection,

This collection items I am store in array, and when remove item from array, it's just removing from `gridView`. But now I want remove like in IOS Photos remove animation.

I can't find any packages doing this animation.
Can we help finding package that remove item from collection with animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here (I didn't test myself) : https://gist.github.com/lukepighetti/df460db180b9f6cb3410e3cc91ed74e6

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Dismissible](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) gesture library.

Thanks to that, you will be able to manage what you want.

edit: here is the [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) with a video.